# SQL creating new column in a view

Tags: sql

my senior tech prepared a view. viewing the source script, i have trouble understanding where the column `label` exists as neither tables contain that column. Is it a column that exists as part of a view - on the fly?

```
select label labelName
, e.name
, e.country 
from entity e
```

source script:

```
SELECT e.entity_id
, se.screen_id
, s.country_code
,desc_trans translatedValue
, et.language_code
, cp.NAME name
FROM entity e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTROL_PREFIX cp 
    ON e.CONTROL_PREFIX_CODE = cp.CONTROL_PREFIX_CODE
, entity_trans et
, screen s
, screen_entity se
WHERE e.entity_id = et.entity_id 
AND e.entity_id = se.entity_id 
AND se.screen_id = s.screen_id 
AND e.entity_type_code = 'LB'

UNION

SELECT e.entity_id
, se.screen_id
, s.country_code
, field_name labelName
, label labelText
, NULL translatedValue
, l.language_code
, cp.NAME name
FROM entity e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTROL_PREFIX cp 
    ON e.CONTROL_PREFIX_CODE = cp.CONTROL_PREFIX_CODE
, language l
, screen s
, screen_entity se
WHERE l.language_code NOT IN
(
    SELECT et1.language_code
    FROM entity e1
    , entity_trans et1
    WHERE e1.entity_id = et1.entity_id 
    AND e1.entity_id = e.entity_id 
    AND e1.entity_type_code = 'LB'
) 
AND e.entity_type_code = 'LB' 
AND s.screen_id = se.screen_id 
AND e.entity_id = se.entity_id;
```

Comment: without the "source script" we can't really help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: SQL server and i also included the source script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the SQL you posted is the SQL used to generate the view and is complete

i.e.

```
create view myView as
select label labelName
, e.name
, e.country 
from entity e
```

Column `Label` is on table `Entity` but appears in the view `myView` as `LabelName`.

If `entity` is the name of the view, you'll need to provide the source behind that view.

Comment: Given `label` appears as a column name in the second part (i.e. after the union statement) and it's not in tables `entity` or `CONTROL_PREFIX` it must be in one of the remaining tables: `language`, `screen`, `screen_entity`.  I suspect you didn't notice them as table names because explicit join statements weren't used - just commas.  Are you able to amend the view - if so I'll post up some cleaner code for you to use (or just replace the commas in the table list with `CROSS JOIN` statements.

Comment: view source script posted.