# Creating views with different columns than table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL table, which has entries out of which one of the columns is date.

table1

```
       ------------------------------------------
       | visit_to | visit_by | visit_on | value |
       ------------------------------------------
            x           a     2015-02-02    1
            x           b     2015-02-16    2
            y           c     2015-02-18    3
```

I want to present the data to the user like this:

table2

```
       -----------------------------------
       | value | Fortnite 1 | fortnite 2 |
       -----------------------------------
           x         a            b
           y                      c
```

now a `fortnite` is from 1st day of the month to 15th day of the same month.
table1 has the list of visits made by `a`, `b` and `c` and the dates of theirs visits, the person `x` gets 2 visits one in each fortnite. And `y` gets only 1 visit in second fortnite.

The table2 should compare these dates and present data in shown format. How can I do this? 
I'm using Sqlite.

Heres what is was able to do:

```
select visit_to, visit_by as fortnite_one
  from visit
  where julianday(date) - julianday('now','start of month','+1 month','-16 day') <= 0 
union
select visit_to, visit_by as fortnite_two
  from visit
  where julianday(date) - julianday('now','start of month','+1 month','-16 day') >= 0
```

But it gives the result for both(fortnite1 and fortnite2) in the `fortnite_one` column only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL creating new column in a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867938/sql-creating-new-column-in-a-view)

Comment: damn that thing goes over my head.

Comment: Is this really the date format you're using in the database? This would make comparisons very hard; why aren't you using one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)?

Comment: no im using `yyyy-mm-dd` habitual of writing like `dd-mm-yyyy` sorry i'll edit it

Comment: you should make the question more clear, like would a person get more than 1 visitor in one fortnite. and the data type of the table if possible.

Comment: The person could get more than one visit, in one fortnite.

Comment: then, there maybe **a,d** in the column **Fortnite 1** for row **x**, where d is another visitor. you better state it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the table and data as below.

```
create table visit (visit_to text, visit_by text, visit_on datetime, value int);
insert into visit values('x', 'a', '2015-02-02 00:00:00', 1);
insert into visit values('x', 'b', '2015-02-16 00:00:00', 2);
insert into visit values('y', 'c', '2015-02-18 00:00:00', 3);
insert into visit values('x', 'd', '2015-02-14 00:00:00', 4);
```

And the query is like this.

```
select
    visit_to,
    date(visit_on, 'start of month') year_month,
    replace(rtrim(group_concat((case when date(date(visit_on, '-15 days'), 'start of month') <> date(visit_on, 'start of month') then visit_by else '' end), (case when date(date(visit_on, '-15 days'), 'start of month') <> date(visit_on, 'start of month') then ' ' else '' end))), ' ', ',') fortnite1,
    replace(rtrim(group_concat((case when date(date(visit_on, '-15 days'), 'start of month') = date(visit_on, 'start of month') then visit_by else '' end), (case when date(date(visit_on, '-15 days'), 'start of month') = date(visit_on, 'start of month') then ' ' else '' end))), ' ', ',') fortnite2
from visit
group by visit_to, date(visit_on, 'start of month')
;
```

You can try http://goo.gl/TXomRO

Hope this help.

Comment: dude, awesome this works, though i'll tweak it a little to give the output i want, bt awesome. thanks a lot :D

Comment: if we want to run this query only for a specific month lets June, can we do that?

Comment: add where date(visit_on, 'start of month') = '2015-06-01' after from and before group by